# Children inheriting parent's colortransform

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How to avoid children inheriting parent's colortransform in flash?

Comment: There is no private messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent/Child relationships are such that children "inherit" transforms applied to parents.  You can't modify a parent without also visually appearing to modify a child.  If a child is supposed to maintain an independent visual state from the parent then you have two options:

1. The child really should not actually be a child, and should be manipulated separately.
2. The child can be a child, but all transforms applied to the parent should also be applied to the child, but inverted.

Unfortunately ColorMatrixFilters aren't that easy to "undo" at the child level, unlike simple x/y/scale properties.  I'd go for option 1 if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

If there a specific visual aspect of the parent that needs to be colorTransformed, then you  could make that mc or sprite a child and then handle it individually as to not affect the other children.

But there's no way to stop the inheritance of that aspect. My suggestion is to alter the design of your movieclip, one potential way is as I described.

Comment: Alter design is good idea but its not possible thats why i ask for help.

Comment: Yep, I understand that all too well. But in this case the difference between working and not working pretty much necessitates a change in design. #1 in the answer selected, is what I suggested, and a change in design. I suggested that you make the visual aspect a child as well -- which is therefore making the other children, not it's child. I had a similar issue recently, and this worked just fine.